# How to clear terminal history

Tags: python3, vim, vimrc

I'm writing as expansion to this blog:
[How to clear the terminal history from vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303805/how-to-clear-the-terminal-history-from-vim)
I have this in my vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType python map <buffer> <F9> :w<CR>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
autocmd FileType python imap <buffer> <F9> <esc>:w<CR>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

But I don't know where to add clear command in it to clear terminal every time I run it again.
I tried do insert it after `<CR>` but it doesn't work.
Can you help me?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Please include text as part of the question not as a picture.

Comment: Ok, but can you help me with my problem?

Comment: did you tried to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm looking for, I want to insert clear somewhere in vimrc code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the answer. In vimrc I add:

```
nmap <F9> <Esc>:w<CR>:!clear;python3 %<CR>
```